# pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN Overclicking

Tags: python, pygame

I have been having trouble with this bit of my code. It display a very basic animation after I click a button. walK() makes the script move to a different animation somewhere else. However when I click the box about 10% of the time it will start spam clicking buttons in other animations. I would appreciate any help.

```
         mouse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
         if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 1235>mouse[0]>1045 and 310>mouse[1]>250 and rand==4:
                    print ('lower right')
                    setDisplay.blit(boz1, (0,0))
                    setDisplay.blit(uc5, (800, 20))
                    pygame.display.update()
                    time.sleep(0.4)
                    setDisplay.blit(boz2, (0,0))               
                    pygame.display.update()
                    time.sleep(0.4)
                    walk()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `if` statement like this;

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.type == 1235>mouse[0]>1045 and event.type == 310>mouse[1]>250 ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but after trying I found that my buttons did not work at all after applying your changes.

Comment: Well then something wrong in your codes because the changes I suggest you are correct, please check your codes again it should be a logic mistake there.

Comment: @Camil Also don't use `sleep()` function in Pygame, really long to explain it why, just don't use it :-) Also use `pygame.display.update()` one time under the codes.

Comment: How can I get same results of sleep() without using it?

Answer (score 0):

First, lets clean up the code a bit. Rather than:

```
1235>mouse[0]>1045 and 310>mouse[1]>250
```

You should use this:

```
pygame.Rect(1045,250,190,60).collidepoint(mouse)
```

This returns True if the point 'mouse' is inside the rectangle. This makes more sense and is easier to read. As mentioned by howaboutNO in the comments, using pygame.time.sleep() is seldom used and should be avoided. I know this doesn't really solve your problem, but we need to see more code, especially your walk() function.